# I want to integrate new application whose docker image is ready with my existing application with kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have my whole project setup ready and deployed, application is running. Now, I want to integrate new service/new application whose docker image is ready. Example, application A is running which contains many micro-services, I want to integrate new service whose docker image is ready, how I can integrate it with the help of docker or kubernetes?

Not specific as I as looking for an idea, what are the possible ways.

Comment: Kubernetes is a container orchestration service it’s provides better scalability options compared to docker, you can have separate [deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) for each microservice and use [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting) for routing the traffic.